# Rapberry Pi SSH Error: packet_write_wait: Connection to 10.42.0.233 Broken pipe

Tags: python, linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux

I tried to write some Python code on my Raspberry Pi 2, but I faced a problem, the problem is that I'm connected to the pi via SSH, but when I try to execute the code below, the terminal window on my computer freezes for 2 to 3 minutes and then this error appear:

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to 10.42.0.233 Broken pipe
```

the Python code that causes this problem is:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)
pwm = GPIO.PWM(12, 50)
pwm.start(5)
```

note that I'm working on the python command line shell and the problem happen just when I execute the last line of the code(pwm.start(5)), please help me and thanks alot

Comment: That's certainly odd. Have you tried other PWM libraries such as [RPIO.PWM](https://pythonhosted.org/RPIO/pwm_py.html)?

Comment: Could it be a power issue? What's connected to the pin?

Comment: gonna try RPIO.PWM, note that I'm powering my pi with a 5V 2A charger

Comment: I've tried this RPIO.PWM it seems it only works on the Pi A,A+, B, B+ but NOT Pi 2

Comment: Ok, I didn't try that library myself and don't have Pi 2 but thought it was worth a try. Does it actually tell you that it won't work for Pi 2 or did you read it somewhere? What's connected to the GPIO pin?

Comment: no I've tried it myself, it doesn't work, just a servo is connected to the GPIO

Comment: Dumb question but... You're not *powering* the servo from GPIOs, are you? : /

Comment: I'm powering the servo from the Raspberry Pi's 5V pin